# Sharp tail bounds for the maximum of an iid sample of a random variable supported on $[0, 1]$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be an iid sample from a distribution supported on $[0, 1]$.

## Question

What are some sharp concentration inequalities (i.e tail bounds) empirical statistic defined by $Z_n := \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ ?

## Observation

Boucheron and co-workers have [results for sub-gaussian and sub-exponential distributions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7209.pdf). These results could in principle be used to obtain rather lax tail bounds bounds for $Z_n$. I was wondering one could do better than such an approach.

Answer (score 2):

For the tail of $Z_n$, we have the very simple exact formula $P(Z_n>t)=1-F(t)^n$ for all real $t$, where $F$ is the cdf of $X_1$. Do you want a bound on it? Of what kind?

Comment: The formula you're proposing is valid for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. My problem is more general. The distribution is only required to **supported** on $[0, 1]$, not necessarily uniform thereupon. Agreed ?

Concerning the remark about my use of "empirical processé", it's in fact not a very interesting process. Fixed.

Comment: Oops, I missed it that the distribution on $[0,1]$ may arbitrary. This does not change the answer much, though.